# Datetime object returns NoneType when I try to compare it to a different date

Tags: python, excel, compare, datetime-format

I got data from excel file and stored it in the list.

Here is a snippet how it looks like in the list (there are thousands of entries):

```
valid = [[227, 30000, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 1, 0, 0)], [228, 20000, datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0)]]
```

If I just print the date, it returns 2020-05-01 00-00-00.

If I check the type, it returns   class 'datetime.datetime'

Now, I want to get only entries of 2020 (here is just a very simplified code):

```
date_to_compare = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
for each in valid:
    if each[2] >= date_to_compare:
        print(each)
```

I receive
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'

Somehow for comparison Python sees the datetime object from Excel as NoneType.

Can anyone help please! 
Thank you.

Comment: Please show your real code. This simplified code works as expected, so the problem is in the parts you skipped/changed.

Answer (score 1):

Some dates in your dataset may not be in the correct format or missing. To work around the bug try this:

```
date_to_compare = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
for each in valid:
    try:
        if each[2] >= date_to_compare:
            print(each)
    except TypeError:
         print(each)
```

Comment: @LenaGavrilov if the answer helps you, please consider accepting it or voting for it.

Comment: I tried, but it says that my reputation is not enough to vote. And I still didn't understand how to raise it.